# Filemaker 17 API "AND" query

Tags: curl, filemaker

I am having a difficult time formulating an "AND" query with the FileMaker 17 API.

Reference:
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#perform-a-find-request

This is being passed into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

```
"{"query":[{
    "uniqueID":"fooBar",
    "anotherField":1
}],"limit":"1"}"
```

What I'd like to have happen is that I retrieve 1 record for which the `uniqueID` is "fooBar" and the `anotherField` is 1.

However, I get the same record if I pass:

```
"{"query":[{
    "uniqueID":"",
    "anotherField":1
}],"limit":"1"}"
```

So this is doing an "OR" lookup.

How can I structure this request so that it performs an "AND" lookup.  In the case of my second example, the query should return no records, as every record in my table has a `uniqueID`?

Updated post-answer:

In my analysis, it seems that the second query in my question simply is an AND for any uniqueID which contains literally *nothing*, which I guess Filemaker somehow interprets as being true for any record.

For someone coming from MySQL, this is very confusing behavior.  And the documentation, while demonstrating this as a global property of FileMaker, is not apparent when looking at the Filemaker API documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an "AND" find. If a field is empty in a find then it will not be searched on. In your counter example you were only searching for fields with anotherField:1. If you want to search on an empty field use "=" as it will only find empty words.

Not enough Rep to comment but for your previous answer:

For Filemaker finds on a uniqueID you would want to use "==" . "=" will give you a word match while "==" will give you an exact value match. See https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/en/html/find_sort.5.6.html

Comment: That's true, but it's a comment on my answer, not the answer to solving "AND" vs "OR"

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't have another rep to comment. Updated

Comment: Updated for AND vs OR answer.

Comment: Accepted your answer!

Comment: The use-case related to my second example, and hence the question, is if you are passing a value which is empty or null.  The right thing to do is error checking and validation of variables, but I still label this odd behavior from a modern DB perspective....

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Agreed re: the Data API documentation. To clarify, for folks who may be visiting this thread later:

```
// this AND that, array with single predicate object

{"query": [{
  "this": "foo",
  "that": "bar"
}]}


// this OR that, array with multiple predicate objects

{"query": [
  {"this": "foo"},
  {"that": "bar"}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I literally ask this a moment ago, but it bears recording, as the Filemaker API documentation is pretty shoddy.

```
"{"query":[{
    "uniqueID":"=fooBar",
    "anotherField":1
}],"limit":"1"}"
```

That returns the record I seek.

The addition of either `=` `==` prevents the false positive, albeit in different ways.

-- Updated to reflect the fine-grained details in Rushfire's answer.

Comment: All queries in your question and in your answer are AND queries, so your answer is incorrect

Comment: I agree that that is technically true, but the documentation is fairly poor.  Technically, the second query in my question simply is an AND for any uniqueID which contains literally nothing, which I guess Filemaker somehow interprets as being true for any record. 

For someone coming from MySQL, this is very confusing behavior.